# Angular2 : Share any data to component on the same level

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ui-router

I'm working on angular2 application. 
And got one question about data sharing. I've found many tutorials how to share data between parent<->child components, but i haven't found answer on question - how to share data to component what is on the same level. 
In my app i use ui-router-ng2 to display main page content where i render content components like sign in/up, profile page etc.
Main app html file:

```
<header-app></header-app>
<div class="main-container container">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

Imagine what in ui-view shows login component and after success login i have to pass data to header component with user info. how could i do it?

Comment: For login and persistent user information I would suggest using a service that is instantiated once (say, in your root module) and then injected around.

Comment: @silentsod could you provide any example what do you mean ? you mean create singleton service what will store data and injected to needed components ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service with

```
@Injectable()

export class ServiceName {
    public valueToStore: datatype //whatever you need


}
```

Inject the service into components where you need to share the data between

```
private valueToBeShared: datatype;
export class Example implements OnInit {
     constructor(private serviceName: ServiceName);


ngOnInit(){
    this.valueToBeShared = this.serviceName.valueToStore;
}
```

Dont forget import Statements for Service an OnInit
Dont forget to add the service to the providers in app.module.ts
And in the Login component you set the value in the service.

```
this.ServiceName.valueToBeStored = whateverYouNeed
```

Comment: this part is clear for me, but ngOnInit for header component work only 1 time when page loads first time. i have one header for all pages, i don't use other header for logged user, only hide/show user name and logout link.